# WPF Print Dialog is not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two forms. In the Form AForm i am trying to call another form BForm and print it. But it is showing an error saying *"file not found"*.However if i tested the same code print the form itself then it is working. Can anyone tell me why? I am using BForm as label.

**Working printing AForm itself**

```
private void btn_printQ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Window Printing.");
}
```

**Not working wanted to print BForm from AForm**

```
private void btn_printQ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    QueueLabel ql = new QueueLabel(QTVM);
    ql.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    printDlg.PrintVisual(ql, "Window Printing.");
    ql.Show();
}
```